# How to clear NLog?

Tags: logging, nlog

I'm using NLog to not only log errors but I make a second log that is basically a user friendly text report for business units. It will let them know that say an employee doesn't have a manager assigned so they will know that they need to fix the issue.

I do this for a couple business unit's inside of our company. I have a console app that runs nightly and will pick up import files for each business unit and process them.

The issue I've come across is that the logging information for each business unit is concatenated to the one before even though I'm creating a new log file for each business unit. So, the first file has only their logging but the second will have both the first and second's, the third will have the first, second, and third's info.

Anyone know of a way that I can clear out the logging in memory to start over for each business unit? I didn't see any kind of .clear method.

This is how I initially create my logging at the top of my class.

```
private static Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("defaultLogger");
private static Logger reportLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("reportLogger");
```

I was looking for something like `reportLogger.Clear()`. I even tried creating a new one like `reportLogger = new Logger();` but that gave me an error that the Logger wasn't accessible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true" 
      throwExceptions="true">

  <variable name="LogDirBase" value="D:\integration\logs\EmployeeFileImport"/>
  <variable name="LogYear" value="${date:format=yyy}"/>
  <variable name="LogMonth" value="${date:format=MM}"/>
  <variable name="LogDay" value="${date:format=dd}"/>
  <variable name="LogFileShortDate" value="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}"/>

  <targets async="true">

    <target name="DefaultTarget"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="${LogDirBase}\${shortdate}.log"
      encoding="utf-8"
      layout="${longdate} | ${callsite} | ${message}"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="7"
      concurrentWrites="true"
    />

    <target name="ReportTarget"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="${LogDirBase}\${shortdate}_Report.txt"
      encoding="utf-8"
      layout="${message}"
      archiveEvery="Day"
      archiveNumbering="Rolling"
      maxArchiveFiles="7"
      concurrentWrites="true"
    />

    <target name="ConsoleTarget"
      xsi:type="Console"
      layout="${longdate} ${logger:shortName=True} ${message}${onexception:EXCEPTION OCCURRED\:${exception:format=type,message,StackTrace,method:maxInnerExceptionLevel=8:innerFormat=type,message,StackTrace,method}}"
    />

  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="defaultLogger" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="DefaultTarget, ConsoleTarget" />
    <logger name="reportLogger" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="ReportTarget" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

UPDATE

I had to push some other code changes last night and now it seems to be working as expected. I didn't make any code changes to the logging so I'm not sure what changed about it. I'll have to keep an eye on the report for the next couple days to see what happens.

Here is how I setup my Log/Report files.

```
static void SetLogFileNames(FileInfo file)
        {
            try
            {
                string logDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LogDirectory"];
                string fileNameOnly = file.Name.ToString().Substring(0, file.Name.Length - 4);


                //*** change the log file name and create one for each file processed. ***
                //*** Need both a Logging file and a Report file to be sent to the business owners. ***
                FileTarget defaultTarget = FindTargetByName("DefaultTarget");
                defaultTarget.FileName = logDirectory + string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now) + "_" + fileNameOnly + ".log";

                FileTarget reportTarget = FindTargetByName("ReportTarget");
                CurrentReportName = string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", DateTime.Now) + "_" + fileNameOnly + "_Report" + ".txt";
                CurrentReportPathName = logDirectory + CurrentReportName;
                reportTarget.FileName = CurrentReportPathName;

                LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateLog(string.Format("Error: setting Log File names. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException), false);
            }  
        }
```

Comment: I think you can do something with the routing. Please post your config! PS interesting case!

Comment: The call LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers() will only help to handle new targets. It will not handle modification to existing targets.

Comment: Why do you have archive configured to use rolling ? Not sure your current filename-format supports this.

Comment: The rolling is probably not needed since I'm creating a new file every day. This is a config file that I picked up from someone else here and I just modified it to meet my needs. It's also a log file that was created over a year ago. Looking it over, there are probably some things that could be cut out of it but I don't think any of it would cause an issue with the data being concatenated and used in another log.

Comment: The NLog Archive logic has many features, but when not configured properly, then sometimes funny behavior can be seen. So better keep it disabled until you have the right configuration.